# Slow motion in Sprite Kit iOS

Tags: ios, performance, sprite, sprite-kit, motion

Does anyone have any good ideas of how to accomplish a slow motion effect in Sprite Kit for iOS? This would make all nodes including particle nodes move at 1/2 the speed and also make the particles move that 1/2 the speed.

I can think of how to do this manually, but I wanted to get some more ideas before I start implementing.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can do:

```
self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.5;
```

The docs reference:

> speed
>
> The rate at which the simulation executes.
>
> @property(nonatomic) CGFloat speed
>   Discussion
>   The default value is 1.0, which means the simulation runs at normal speed. A value other than the default changes the rate at which time passes in the physics simulation. For example, a speed value of 2.0 indicates that time in the physics simulation passes twice as fast as the scene’s simulation time. A value of 0.0 pauses the physics simulation.
>
> Availability
>   Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
>   Declared In
>   SKPhysicsWorld.h

Comment: Note that this should be in your SKScene subclass.

Comment: for some reason any speed that doesn't equal 1.0 makes all movements not perfectly (visually) smooth... any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In update method where you calculate movement speed everywhere when calculations are done multiply the movement by some variable, have it be 1 by default. But when you need slow motion set it to 0.5.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea for movement, but I'm not sure if there is a way I could slow down particle effects without creating all new particle effects. It all feels really manual. I was hoping there'd be something like .slow = .5    :)

Comment: @brilliantairic there is speed property on particle emitter, you can multiply it by same value. Birth rate can be useful too